# plot python from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot, group-by

My dataframe below is for a certain value in the column "IdBox"=4. It helps me to do a plot of the data only for "IdBox"=4.
I cannot find a way to have a function to plot this more quickly when IdBox value changes. My IdBox value ranges from 4 to 9, which means 6 graphs.

```
chaudiere4 = yy[(yy.NameDeviceType== "Chaudière_logement") & (yy.IdBox == 4.0)]

In [898]: chaudiere4    
Out[898]:
UnitDeviceType  NameDeviceType  IdBox   IdDeviceValue             ValueDeviceValue  weekday hour    ONOFF
DateDeviceValue                             
2015-11-27 17:54:00 On/Off  Chaudière_logement  4.0 536448.0    On  4.0 17.0    1
2015-11-27 17:54:00 On/Off  Chaudière_logement  4.0 536449.0    Off 4.0 17.0    0
2015-11-27 17:54:00 On/Off  Chaudière_logement  4.0 536450.0    On  4.0 17.0    1
2015-11-27 17:54:00 On/Off  Chaudière_logement  4.0 536451.0    Off 4.0 17.0    0
2015-11-27 18:09:00 On/Off  Chaudière_logement  4.0 536453.0    On  4.0 18.0    1
```

I created a column called ONOFF and grouped by mean to do the plot.

```
chaudiere4 = chaudiere4['ONOFF'].groupby(chaudiere4['hour']).mean()

chaudiere4.plot(kind='bar')
plt.title("Chaudiere ON/OFF")
plt.xlabel('hour')
plt.legend('ONOFF')
plt.axis([0, 24, 0, 1])
plt.show()
```

Is there a way to do this quickly with a function instead of changing the dataframe to chaudiere5 for Idbox=5 and chaudiere6 for Idbox=6?

Comment: you want to plot a graph for each chaudière ?

Comment: Indeed, I am looking for a fast way to do it instead of repeating this whole code 6 times

Comment: @cloclo, is [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42493407/plot-python-from-dataframe#comment72126558_42493491) what you want?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC:

```
yy[(yy.NameDeviceType== "Chaudière_logement") & (yy.IdBox == 4.0)] \
  .groupby('hour')['ONOFF'].mean() \
  .plot.bar()
```

You can create a little function for that:

```
def my_plot(df, IdBox=0, title='Chaudiere ON/OFF'):
    df[(df.NameDeviceType== "Chaudière_logement") & (df.IdBox == IdBox)] \
      .groupby('hour')['ONOFF'].mean() \
      .plot.bar(title=title)
    plt.axis([0, 24, 0, 1])
    plt.show()
```

now you can call it like this:

```
my_plot(df, 4.0)
```

Comment: I think what he wants is to change this portion `(yy.IdBox == 4.0)` to have values 4, 5, and 6 and create a plot for each. This can be achieved using a simple `for` loop?

Comment: why IDBox is y_plot(df, IdBox=0) on the first line and (df.IdBox == 4.0)] on the second line? The graph works but I need to change the IdBox each time.

Comment: what would it be in this case?